# Running test without compile in SBT - how-to

Tags: testing, sbt

I'm new to SBT and I would like to know if it is possible to run tests without compiling. I mean to use a set of classes that have been already compiled.

Is this possible and what should I do to get this done?

Comment: Can you explain the reason?  Is it because some code isn't compiling?  Or, do you mean running tests on jars that were compiled on another machine, for example.

Comment: Mark, you are right your example is correct and that is the reason of my question. Is that possible ?

Comment: Which example of the two?  They are different situations.

Comment: Running tests on jars that were compiled on another machine.

Comment: Mark do you know if this is possible ?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't readily possible, no.  Please open a bug.

Answer (score 0):

sbt detects the available tests during compilation for efficiency.  To run already compiled tests that are on the classpath and not in source files, it would be necessary to explicitly list them in the `definedTests` task.  This isn't too straightforward, though.